# How to build a custom control using recursion?

Tags: c#, wpf, recursion, mvvm

I am trying to build a rather complex custom control.

I want to use recursion in my View Model to build out a control. I will try and be as clear as possible.

I have two classes, Publisher and Developer

The Publisher class looks like the following:

```
public class Publisher
{
  public Publisher()
  {
    SubPublishers.CollectionChanged += SubPublishers_CollectionChanged;
    ChildDevelopers.CollectionChanged += SubPublishers_CollectionChanged;
  }

  private ObservableCollection<Publisher> subPublishers;
  public ObservableCollection<Publisher> SubPublishers
  {
    get
    {
       if (subPublishers == null)
           subPublishers = new ObservableCollection<Publisher>();
       return subPublishers;
    }
  }

  private ObservableCollection<Developer> childDevelopers;
  public ObservableCollection<Developer> ChildDevelopers
  {
    get
    {
       if (childDevelopers == null)
           childDevelopers = new ObservableCollection<Developer>();
       return childDevelopers;
    }
  }
```

And my Developer Class looks like this:

```
public class Developer : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public Developer(string Title)
   {
     this.Title = Title;
   }

   private string title;
   public string Title
   {
     get
     {
       return this.title;
     }
     set
     {
       this.title = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("Title");
     }
   }
```

So yes, Publisher is n-tier. It can have a Collection of Developers and each of these Developers can have their own Collection of Developers.

Going to my Main View Model:

```
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public MainViewModel()
   {
     this.ParentPublisher = new ParentPublisher();
     BuildData();
   }

   private Publisher parentPublisher;
   public Publisher ParentPublisher
   {
     get
     {
       return this.parentPublisher;
      }
     set
     {
       this.parentPublisher = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("ParentPublisher"); 
      }
    }

   public void BuildData()
   {
     Publisher firstPublisher = new Publisher();
     firstPublisher.ChildDevelopers.Add(new Developer("HAL"));
     firstPublisher.ChildDevelopers.Add(new Developer("Retro Games"));
     firstPublisher.ChildDevelopers.Add(new Developer("Nintendo"));

     Publisher secondPublisher = new Publisher();
     secondPublisher.ChildDevelopers.Add(new Developer("343"));
     secondPublisher.ChildDevelopers.Add(new Developer("Playground Games"));
     secondPublisher.SubPublishers.Add(new Publisher());

     secondPublisher.SubPublishers.FirstOrDefault().ChildDevelopers.Add(new Developer("Coalition"));
     secondPublisher.SubPublishers.FirstOrDefault().ChildDevelopers.Add(new Developer("Remedy"));
     secondPublisher.SubPublishers.FirstOrDefault().SubPublishers.Add(new Publisher());

     secondPublisher.SubPublishers.FirstOrDefault().SubPublishers.FirstOrDefault().ChildDevelopers.Add(new Developer("Insomniac"));
     secondPublisher.SubPublishers.FirstOrDefault().SubPublishers.FirstOrDefault().ChildDevelopers.Add(new Developer("Criterion"));
     secondPublisher.SubPublishers.FirstOrDefault().SubPublishers.FirstOrDefault().ChildDevelopers.Add(new Developer("EA"));

    ParentPublisher.Add(firstPublisher);
    ParentPublisher.Add(secondPublisher);
  }
 }
}
```

So, you can see the possible scenarios here. Now, I was trying to figure out how to build a control off this data.

I want to actually bind to the ParentPublisher because everything added (SubPublishers and the Child Developers) will ultimately be extension of the Parent.

Would I use an ObservableCollection and use the ItemSource to this ParentPublisher?

Any tips or recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that shows that "`Developer` is n-tier". `Publisher` on the other hand...

Comment: You're right, I edited it. Sorry for that.

Comment: I think you'd do better using recursion in your view to build out the control. This is what hierarchicaldatatemplate is intended for and it's how the treeview works. For example. You missed out one particularly important part of an explanation.  If I saw the view, what would it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to make a `UserControl` that excepts the first tier as a DataTemplate.  Then you show the data in the `DataTemplate` as needed.  Inside the `DataTemplate` reference the `UserControl` again with the inner data.

Example:  Obviously modify the layout to benefit you but for simplicity I did it this way.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF_Question_Answer_App.PublisherView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Question_Answer_App"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450"
             d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DeveloperTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" /> <!--show the developer data-->
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="PublisherTemplate">
            <local:PublisherView /> <!-- reference ourself for recursion-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ChildDevelopers}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DeveloperTemplate}" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SubPublishers}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PublisherTemplate}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```